# Get XML Value (Location) from multiple rows using PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get the values of location from a xml file using php:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <GEC LOCATION="rm1" TECHNICIAN="19">
    <FIELDS>
        <FIELD ID="1" LABEL="ID:" VALUE="2" />
        <FIELD ID="9" LABEL="LOC:" VALUE="rm1" />
        <FIELD ID="22" LABEL="TECH:" VALUE="19" />
    </FIELDS>
 </GEC>
```

My attempt: through php

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/file.xml');
 $getLocation = $xml->FIELD[LABEL];
 echo $getLocation;
 //this outputs only ID:
```

What I would like it to grab is the Location and tried:

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/file.xml');
 $getLocation = $xml->FIELDS[3]->FIELD[VALUE]; //or FIELD[LABEL]
 echo $getLocation;
 //this outputs nothing
```

I also tried getting from the main GEC

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file('xml/file.xml');
 $getLocation = $xml->GEC[LOCATION];
 echo $getLocation;
 //nothing
```

I'm not sure what I am missing. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way using XPath expression as selector :

```
$string = <<<XML
<GEC LOCATION="rm1" TECHNICIAN="19">
    <FIELDS>
        <FIELD ID="1" LABEL="ID:" VALUE="2" />
        <FIELD ID="9" LABEL="LOC:" VALUE="rm1" />
        <FIELD ID="22" LABEL="TECH:" VALUE="19" />
    </FIELDS>
 </GEC>
XML;
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string);
$getLocation = $xml->xpath("//FIELD[@LABEL='LOC:']/@VALUE")[0];
echo $getLocation;
```

**<kbd>[`eval.in demo`](https://eval.in/405674)</kbd>**

brief explanation about the XPath being used :

- `//FIELD` : Find `<FIELD>` element(s), anywhere in the XML document...
- `[@LABEL='LOC:']` : ...having attribute `LABEL` value equals `LOC:`
- `/@VALUE` : from such `FIELD`, return the `VALUE` attribute

**output :**

```
rml
```

Comment: Cool thank you.  Would this work in a foreach loop importing about 100 xml files all the same attributes but different values?

Comment: @smor yes this should work fine, as long as the XMLs structure are the same (especially those that is mentioned in the XPath expression)

Comment: Thank you very much it worked even running through the foreach.  I added simplexml_load_file inside the foreach to import all files then $getLocation = $xml->xpath("//FIELD[@LABEL='LOC:']/@VALUE")[0]; and echo'd the $getLocation;.. I appreciate the help @har07 and ramRaider!!!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used simplexml so this might not be the way you wish to go but the following can be easily modified to suit your needs perhaps.

```
            $data='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
             <GEC LOCATION="rm1" TECHNICIAN="19">
                <FIELDS>
                    <FIELD ID="1" LABEL="ID:" VALUE="2" />
                    <FIELD ID="9" LABEL="LOC:" VALUE="rm1" />
                    <FIELD ID="22" LABEL="TECH:" VALUE="19" />
                </FIELDS>
             </GEC>';


            libxml_use_internal_errors( TRUE );
            $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0','utf-8');
            $dom->validateOnParse=false;
            $dom->standalone=TRUE;
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace=TRUE;
            $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
            $dom->substituteEntities=FALSE;
            $dom->recover=TRUE;
            $dom->formatOutput=false;

            /* Rather than loading the xml from a static string
               you might wish to use the following instead:- 
             $dom->loadXML( file_get_contents('path/to/file.xml') );
            */
            $dom->loadXML( $data );
            $parse_errs=serialize( libxml_get_last_error() );
            libxml_clear_errors();


            $col=$dom->getElementsByTagName('FIELD');
            foreach( $col as $node ) echo $node->getAttribute('ID').' '.$node->getAttribute('LABEL').' '.$node->getAttribute('VALUE').'<br />';
            $dom=null;


            /* Will print out */
            /*
             1 ID: 2
             9 LOC: rm1
             22 TECH: 19
            */
```

Comment: Thanks for the information!  This something I'll try and let you know.